# Set based approach to SQL Server insert where one column is calculated as Max from same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering if this is one of those situations where I'm forced to use a cursor or if I can use a set based approach.  I've searched for several hours and also tried to come up with a solution myself to no avail.

I've got a table, SuperSupplierCodes, that contains two columns:  SuperSupplierCode INT, and SupplierName NVARCHAR(50).

```
SuperSupplierID SupplierName
1               21ST CENTURY GRAPHIC TECHNOLOGIES LLC
2               3D SYSTEMS
3               3G
4               A A ABRASIVOS ARGENTINOS SAIC
5               A AND F DRUCKLUFTTECHNIK GMBH
6               A BAY STATIONERS
7               A C T TOOL AND ENGINEERING LLC
8               A HERZOG AG
9               A LI T DI MONTANARI MARCO AND CO SAS
11              A RAYMOND GMBH AND CO KG
```

I've got a second table with millions of rows in it containing financial data as well as the SupplierName column.

```
LocalSupplierName
23 JAN HOFMEYER ROAD
303 TAXICAB, LLC
3D MECA SARL
3D SYSTEMS
3E CO ENVIRONMENTAL, ECO. & EN
3E COMPANY
```

What I need to do is insert into the SuperSupplierCodes table such that each row gets the MAX(SuperSupplierCode) from the previous row, increments it by one, and inserts that into the SuperSupplierCode column along with the SupplierName from the second table.

I've tried the following, just as a test, that I might be able to use for the insert, but of course it will only do the increment once and try to use that same value for SuperSupplierCode for every row:

```
SELECT s.SuperSupplierID,
   s.SupplierName,
   s.SupplierAddress,
   s.DateCreated,
   s.DateModified,
   s.SupplierCode,
   s.PlantName,
   s.id,
   x.MaxSSC
FROM SuperSupplierCodes AS s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(SuperSupplierID)+1 AS MaxSSC FROM dbo.SuperSupplierCodes) x;
```

I don't like using cursors unless I absolutely have to.  Is there a way to do this with T-SQL in a set based manner versus using a cursor?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use an auto increment column here?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I might be able to use an auto increment and have it start at a certain value.  The problem I'm having is that I have to do an insert from another table that already contains the SuperSupplierCode for a number of suppliers, and they need to match up.  The customer created the SuperSupplierCode for thousands of suppliers already and wants me to use them.  That insert is no problem, it's getting the rest of the suppliers, that don't have a SuperSupplierCode yet, into this SuperSupplierCode table.  I'll try to add some sample data here in a minute.

Comment: I gusee you could make a row_number then `join` then use `LEAD` function.

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE`, setting it to the highest value already present when you create it, then keep peeling off `NEXT VALUE FOR`s as you `INSERT` your new data?  Okay, it's manual, but it's one manual step for what seems very much like a "once in a while" task, and it avoids having to change your database table to used an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Use a window function such as row_number() for the SELECT part and add max(existing keys in target table) to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
SELECT  (SELECT MAX(SuperSupplierID) FROM dbo.SuperSupplierCodes) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.DateCreated) AS SuperSupplierID,
   s.SupplierName,
   s.SupplierAddress,
   s.DateCreated,
   s.DateModified,
   s.SupplierCode,
   s.PlantName,
   s.id
FROM SuperSupplierCodes AS s;
```

We use the above technique at my work all the time when inserting rows. If some have existing values, you can insert them all into the table and then change the above to only update values that are currently null.

Comment: Oh man, I knew there was a way to do it, I just couldn't figure it out.  Thanks so much, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

Create the column as an identity and insert the existing records once using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON option. Then switch it off for adding new Ids and they will be incremented.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017